# Having trouble printing an array with functions

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

Program will not print the array, it is just blank. It will let me build with no errors but there is one warning statement:

> `warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int (__cdecl *)(int)'`

I'd like to use a pointer in the program which is why it is in it due to chapter for class.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define count 7

int form1(int a);
int form2(int a);
int form3(int a);
int form4(int a);
int form5(int a);
int form6(int a);
int form7(int a);

int main()
{
    //creates a pointer to the functions for the program
    int (*forms[count])(int) = { form1, form2, form3, form4, form5, form6 ,form7 };


    //prints out the array for sizeof data types
    for (unsigned int i = 1;i >= count;i++) {
        printf("%s", forms[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
int form1(int a) {
    a = sizeof(char);
    return a;
}
int form2(int a) {
    a = sizeof(short);
    return a;
}
int form3(int a) {
    a = sizeof(int);
    return a;
}
int form4(int a) {
    a = sizeof(long);
    return a;
}
int form5(int a) {
    a= sizeof(long long);
    return a;
}
int form6(int a) {
    a= sizeof(float);
    return a;
}
int form7(int a) {
    a= sizeof(double);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: `for (unsigned int i = 1;i >= count;i++)` `count = 7`and `i = 1` which is lesser than `7` so you never enter on the `for`loop

Answer (score 5):

Three things are wrong:

1. `printf` should use `%d` to print out an `int`, not `%s`. `%s` indicates you are printing a `char*`, as your compiler has told you. Further, you need to use parentheses after `forms[i]` (i.e., `forms[i]()`) in order to call it properly; otherwise you are printing the pointer to the function itself, and not the result of the function call. Note that I didn't include any arguments in my function call. This is because of point 2 below.
2. There is absolutely no rhyme or reason to pass in a parameter that is immediately thrown away and returned. Instead of `int form1(int a) { a = sizeof(char); return a; }`, for example, use `int form1() { return sizeof(char); }` If you do this, you will also need to change your declaration of `*forms` to `int (*forms[count])() = { ... };`
3. Your `for` loop should read `unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++`.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Works perfectly...Thank You